# Fastboot commands doesn't work on Amazon Fire tablet

Tags: twrp, fastboot, amazon-kindle-fire

I've got an Amazon Fire 5th Generation tablet that I want to boot TWRP on, but when I do `fastboot boot n:/twrp.img`, I get this:

```
Sending 'boot.img' (7946 KB)       
OKAY [  0.265s]
Booting                                            
FAILED (remote: 'the command you input is restricted on locked hw')                                             
fastboot : error: Command failed
```

Might be because I need to unlock the bootloader? If it is, how?

Comment: I'm getting the same error on an Amazon Fire HD 8 8th gen when trying to unlock the bootloader, so unlocking the bootloader isn't a way around it.